# Using "toRightOf" programatically when inflating a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-inflate

I have an XML layout looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="1"/>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- Define these into code
        <TextView android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="1"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="1"/>-->

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `TextView`s inside `LinearLayout` are not meant to be changed. `RelativeLayout` also consists of `TextView`s which are aligned `5dp` away from each other. Unlike the parent layout's ones, they need to be defined inside my Java activity. This is what I have tried:

```
private View getGeneratedView(String[] texts) {
    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View parentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
    RelativeLayout childLayout = (RelativeLayout) parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.child);

    Integer lastViewId = null;
    for (String text: texts) {
        TextView displayedText = new TextView(this);
        displayedText.setText(text);
        displayedText.setTextSize(20);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (lastViewId != null) {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, lastViewId);
            params.leftMargin = 5;
        }
        displayedText.setLayoutParams(params);

        lastViewId = displayedText.getId();
        childLayout.addView(displayedText);
    }

    return parentLayout;
}
```

But what the code above does is putting all of the `TextView`s in the center, the one on top of the other like so:
[image: layout processed inside Java]
(parameter `texts` was `new String[] {"1", "1", "1", "1"}`)

And this is what I am trying to get:
[image: xml defined layout]

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are generating a new `TextView` for each string in `texts`, you do not generate an id for it. As a result, `displayedText.getId()` will always be -1 ([`View.NO_ID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#NO_ID)) and `lastViewId` will never be other than -1.

To correct the code, you need to generate a new id for each generated `TextView`. With API 17+, you can use `View.generateViewId()` to do this.

```
private View getGeneratedView(String[] texts) {
    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View parentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
    RelativeLayout childLayout = (RelativeLayout) parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.child);

    Integer lastViewId = null;
    for (String text : texts) {
        TextView displayedText = new TextView(this);
        // Need API 17+ for generateViewId
        displayedText.setId(View.generateViewId());
        displayedText.setText(text);
        displayedText.setTextSize(20);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (lastViewId != null) {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, lastViewId);
            params.leftMargin = 5;
        }
        displayedText.setLayoutParams(params);

        lastViewId = displayedText.getId();
        childLayout.addView(displayedText);
    }

    return parentLayout;
}
```